# What does "used" mean when calling a method of a class

Tags: java, eclipse

Everything worked fine before I renamed my old class since I messed it up too much and wanted to start again by copying everything that works.

Now I get this strange "**- used**" thingy when I try to call a method within the same class.

I thought it's because the old class had the same method and variable names so I renamed them all. I also renamed my new class's variables and methods but it shows this again.

I couldn't find the right terminology in order to find the answer, so if this means something else than what I thought, please enlighten me! Thanks!

Here's a screenshot:

[image: CLICK ME]

Comment: I think it's stating that those methods have already been used in that same statement (vs. the % value associated with `getClass()` which should be a guess about you are looking for that method)

Comment: That the function is used in your codebase?

Comment: I didn't have this before and everything worked fine. Now my .equals method fails during the tests. While it worked before. I am in Eclipse.

Comment: @A.D. When you renamed your class, did you use eclipses refactor option, or did you just manually re-write the name? 
edit: also, please tell us the name of the exception that is being thrown on failure.

Comment: yeah i also don't know what does this 21% mean, actually, but i don't care too much abt that atm, more thinking that this -used fails my test

Comment: I think it literally means that you use this method. Either in the class itself, or elsewhere in the project. Remove all the places where you call that method and see if the tag goes away.

Comment: The percentage is probably how likely it is for a given option to be the correct completion, according to autocomplete's algorithm. Just guessing though.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips I used refactor, but then even moved the class out of the src folder, so it's in a completely different place now (well.. just one level up. but still). The error is `java.lang.AssertionError`. I am basically just doing `AssertTrue(object1.equals(object2))`

Comment: This is just an autocomplete window. Don't treat it too seriously. In fact, completely disregard it and go ahead and properly debug your code.

Comment: very weird, because I renamed all my methods and these are the new method names which I use there only. Okay and in one more method, but I did call them with the old names in the old class in the same other methods and they used to work just fine. (hope you get what I mean). P.S. i'm a girl, sorry, just learning :D

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried to debug it and it fails exactly at this method at exatly this place on the screenshots because it doesn't evaluate my values as equal it doesn't do within the if statement to change the boolean value that'd say my objects are the same

Comment: set a breakpoint to right before your method fails. Look at the values for all your variables and verify that they are what you intend them to be.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using `==` in a lot of places where you should be using `.equals(...)`

Comment: yes, i debugged it and also ensure the values are correct. However my program doesn't think so. So it's not the -used tag somehow? Then I will keep searching.

Comment: If you want debugging help, you will have to post actual code as text, with a self-contained *minimal* example that reproduces the error.

Comment: I can assure you eclipse's autocomplete has nothing to do with your code being messed up by you :)

Comment: To follow up on @MadPhysicist about using `==` with strings: When you use `==` to compare strings, the contents of the strings are not compared. what is compared is the location in memory of the strings.
so in the case of
`String firstString = "a";`
`String secondString = "a;"`
 `(firstString == secondString)` will evaluate as `false`, although `(firstString == firstString)` will evaluate as `true`.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips Thanks! But I am comparing this way because this is my custom .equals() method, what's the best practice then? Can I use the java's default .equals() method in my custom .equals() method? Makes not sense because that default one also checks the address afaik?

Comment: You are comparing strings, which have *their* own custom `equals` method. `string1 == string2` checks addresses only. `object1.equals(object2)` checks addresses only. However, `string1.equals(string2)` actually checks if the strings are equal in terms of their contents.

Comment: There are many different `.equals()` methods that exist within the Java libraries. Which one gets called is dependent on what `Class` is being used to call the object. if you have a `String` object, for example `String firstString = "a"` and you say `firstString.equals(secondString)` the method will be called from the `String` `Class`, because firstString is a string, and the `.` that comes after `firstString` is saying "reference methods within the class of the object that comes before this `.`"

Comment: to simply all this, you **have** to use `.equals()` to get the results that you are attempting to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentages and `- used` are information provided by [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/).

The **percentages** are a ranking system: some code completion proposals with a high percentage are displayed at the top. The icons of these preferred/recommended proposals are marked with a star.

**`used`** instead of a percentage value are special cases: these **proposals have already been applied on the same variable** in your code. This **helps to avoid mistakes** such as `point.setX(1);point.setX(2);` instead of `point.setX(1);point.setY(2);`. Also if using a getter method that requires an extensive calculation, a variable is preferable to multiple calls. See `used` as a warning to choose the proposal at the current position, not as an error.