# eclipse suggestions with percentage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am using eclipse oxygen and JDK 1.8 
When We enter `ctl+space`  then eclipse give suggestions or shows all methods of respective class.
There is some percentage shows[Refer image] what is it for?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614159/6505250